# Java: returning object of same class(which have common parent class) passed

Tags: java, inheritance

I was doing something like below but it returns object of base class rather than subclass.

```
public static BaseVo getObject(String objID, Class<? extends BaseVo> cls) {
    BaseVo obj = constructObject(objID, cls);
    return obj;
}
```

Ofcourse actual obj is of subclass, I can easily typecast after returning. But I wanted to find a way so that every function do not have to typecast after calling getObject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the method generic.

```
public static <T extends BaseVo> T getObject(String objID, Class<T> cls) {
    T obj = constructObj(objID, cls);
    return obj;
}
```

This assumes that `constructObj` can be modified to return `T` as well.

Comment: shouldn't it be `Class<T extends BaseVo>`?.

Comment: No. The constraint is on the *definition* of the generic, not on the usage on the right.

Comment: @TheLostMind The type parameter `T` is already defined as extending `BaseVo`. You don't need to (can't) restate that information.

Comment: You might just as well drop the `T obj = …` and return immediately. I know this is how the OP had it, though.

Comment: In some cases, `Class<? super T> cls` can be more useful; but then the compiler may or may not be able to infer the type `T` correctly. E.g. when `T` is `ArrayList<Integer>` (because `ArrayList<Integer>.class` does not work!)